# SSD with Arch Linux not booting after adding another SSD

Tags: arch-linux, boot, partition, ssd

I added a new SSD to the desktop machine that had an SSD with Arch Linux (wuth a rolling distro, no specific version). After I tried to boot, I had an error:

```
Initramfs unpacking failed: invalid magic at start of compressed archive
```

This is the full message:
[image]

What could cause the problem? Before the OS was loading properly. I am planning to boot from the USB and check partitions (didn't have a bootable USB with me today). Thanks in advance!

Comment: If it boots normally on disconnecting the new SSD: check your BIOS boot priority or swap the cables at the drive end to the old drive has higher priority.

Comment: It doesn't boot normally on disconnecting the new SSD, that is the problem. The error is the same.

Answer (score -1):

After I used live USB and partitioned the new SSD with Gparted from there, the previous SSD was able to boot. Not sure what was the issue, but it is solved now. It might be that before I was connecting the SSDs in a different order (there is another HDD connected too), but not sure why the issue remained when I was disconnecting the new SSD. Anyway, better to always have a live USB at hand.

Comment: This is not an answer.